# What could be causing massive memory peaks in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, memory, optimization

Upon running my code I get:
[image: this]

Constantly peaking between 4 and 12MB multiple times a second.

[Here is the full thing.](http://reasoner.comoj.com/swarm/)

I've narrowed it down to be likely in the draw() function or the settarget() function, but I cannot figure out what is causing so much garbage.

[This is the code](http://reasoner.comoj.com/swarm/swarm.js)

What in there could be causing this much garbage?

Comment: Take a look how many `for`s do you have on this script.

Comment: i get at least 10 errors in the console maybe you should check them out first.

Comment: Works for me.  @camus - are you running in Chrome?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann I know, but a for loop along does not generate garbage.

Comment: @camus I only get two errors, and that's because it calls a function in the wrong order. That doesn't break anything though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can glean using [Chrome's Heap Profiler](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling) it kind of looks like you're creating a lot of Arrays, Numbers, and Strings.  (Not surprising for an animation like this.)  This line looks suspicious to me:

```
rgbcolor = 'rgb('+Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+')';
```

It's called for every dot on every frame, and creates (at least) one new String object, plus the various Number-related stuff that Math does under the hood.

That said, is this causing actual problems for you, or is it just that the saw-tooth memory profile is bugging you?  This sort of memory profile is not at all uncommon for garbage-collected runtimes, and the fact the peaks of your sawtooth don't increase over time would seem to indicate you don't actually have a memory leak anywhere.  And, too, Chrome (and most modern browsers) are very good at optimizing code that creates transient objects like this.

Comment: No actual problems for me, I just felt that peaks of 12MB memory usage seemed high. then again, maybe not.

Also, I took out the lines of code pertaining to color, and just set it to #fff, and the sawtooth pattern remains unchanged.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like the garbage collector is only responsible for ~1% of CPU (using Profiles -> CPU Profile tool)

Comment: Okay, I never really understood the profile tool. Well since the memory doesn't increase over time, I suppose it's not a big problem. the main thing now is that it uses 80% of my cpu in total to run it. Would that be possible to hand over to the gpu?

Comment: It's a pretty demanding animation so I'm not surprised it's using that much CPU.  You could use the Profile -> CPU Profile tool to drill into performance there a bit - which currently indicates that animLoop and settarget are the two most cpu-intensive functions (no surprise there I expect).  There might be techniques for offloading some of the graphics rendering to the GPU, but I'm not familiar with that problem space.  I expect it'd start with using a `webgl` canvas context instead of a `2d` context.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGL/Getting_started_with_WebGL

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look into it. I'll try to optimize the settarget function, due to the fact that it is a for loop in a for loop and does more than 10 million checks a second in total :/

Comment: Oh, also forgot to mention. 

`rgbcolor = 'rgb('+Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*256)+')';`

Isn't called for every dot on every frame, but for every dots once every few seconds, it's only when the audio peaks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think its this line here:

```
 window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);.
```

If you look at the details under `Memory` in the console tools you will see that the animation frame is being fired, and then re-fired and then re-fired every `17ms` which happens to be `1000/60` rounded up.

You can open the initial call to:

```
(function animloop() {
window.requestAnimFrame(animloop);
```

And you will see that every `17ms` after that your process spawned itself again.

Comment: What does this have to do with memory consumption?

Comment: @broofa what does that not have to do with memory consumption? every time it spawns the process it requests the animation frame - and it's hundreds of elements. Any time you spawn any process its going to consume memory...

Comment: Yes but that's sort of the point of the whole thing, the animation. It's essentially an interval timer, what would you do instead?

Comment: I agree that requestAnimationFrame() is a probably a better API for setting up the timer, but it's optimized (in most browsers) to run at 60FPS.  So it's not like it's going to make that much of a difference here.  And JS only has a single process - it's not spawning new processes (hence no process-related overhead - it's just queueing the timer callback to be scheduled in the next JS event loop.

The problem here is not how to slow down the animation, it's how to reduce the memory consumed for the current animation demands.

Comment: @LiamBigelow I know its the point, he asked why it was spiking, so I answered. It's not that its a bad thing, its just the reason he gets that memory profile.

Comment: @broofa, I never suggested that he should slow it down, or that it was even a problem. The title of the question is "what is causing these memory peaks", my answer literally shows the exact line that's causing it. Nothing else.

Comment: @ryan - The peaks are caused by user-memory consumption and garbage collection behavior.  Saying the timer is the cause is like saying high gas prices are caused by the people who start their cars each morning.  Technically true, but not helpful.